# How to reference a variable of Domain class in my method

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-tool-suite

I want to check if a boolean variable from a Domain class equates to true in my method.

```
private Boolean exampleName1 = null;
```

This is in a @Entity class called Javaclass1.java

My method is in JavaClass2.java

```
public static String myMethod(name1, nameClass){
   if(nameClass != null){
       return name1;
  }
}
```

I want to execute the if condition above only if the boolean for exampleName1 in the entity class is true. It has a getter and setter.
How would I import and setup the if condition?

Comment: Unclear. How are your classes related? What is `nameClass` (hint: your code does not compile). Where are the entity instances created and where do instances of your other class exist? Why can't you pass a reference of one to the other and then call the getter?

Comment: I wanted to know how to import and use it inside the method. Like how would I use exampleName1 inside the method. Im a beginner at this.
Can I do like a 
public static Javaclass1 javaClass1;
Then do like if(javaClass1.exampleName1 == true){}, then add the remaining if condition inside the method

Comment: There are many different ways how to "use" the field of a class in another class, it all depends on what you want your program to do (inject in constructor, construct new instance, pass as method parameter, have a singleton, expose via other class, create from factory, look up in container, …). Note that "import" has a very specific meaning in Java and one does not generally "import a class into a method". Private fields are generally not accessible from other classes.

Comment: got it ill look into each of those details. Thanks for the direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a private attribute from another entity (in your example something like `getExampleName1()`) you should have instance of that entity at first. you should import your entity by Name and then call the getter name. for example:

```
public static String myMethod(String name1, String nameClass, Javaclass1 javaClass1){
   if(nameClass != null && javaClass1.getExampleName1 == true ){
       return name1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I pass in the private attribute of the entity without having to change the parameters for myMethod?

Comment: No, you can reach them just by call their getters

Comment: and one thing more please add datatypes in your methods signs like
 ```public static String myMethod(String name1, String nameClass, Javaclass1 javaClass1)```

Comment: You're welcome
Hope be a great developer. keep trying...

Comment: All these different concepts and ways to do certain things I feel is never-ending. There always a better way to do something. My head gets fried at times.